# FQL call to get friends photos with location timing out

Tags: facebook-graph-api, timeout, facebook-fql

I have the following FQL query to get any photos with location information attached from Facebook friends.

```
SELECT 
object_id, owner, album_object_id, place_id, src_big, src_small, caption 
FROM photo 
WHERE owner IN( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ) AND place_id!=''
```

The call works if the logged in user has a small number of friends(30~50).

For users with a higher number of active friends (200+) I get a 500 from the API end point with the following message

```
{
    "error_code":1,
    "error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"
}
```

I tried the call in [Graph API exploder](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) but it simply times out.